# How to re-request for certain access tokens in Facebook API for iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using the following line of code, I've requested the user to accept the permissions.

```
loginButton.readPermissions =
                @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"];
```

In the simulator, I've granted access only for public-profile and email.
Later I wanted to grant an access token for user-friends but the dialog for granting permission no longer appears.
It instead says that "You have already authorized this app" and shows up a Cancel and Ok button.

please help me out! Thanks in advance!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the facebook account you have logged in. In the app settings in that fb account https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications remove the app you have given permission to. Then login in  from the app again you could see the facebook window requesting you  new permissions and the old ones

Comment: Thanks but is there any work around to re-request the declined permissions with out having to remove the entire app from settings?

Comment: check this link about how to ask for permissions that are declined or new permissions that are added after the initial login https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/permissions